# Run web service eclipse - apache tomcat 8

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, web-services, tomcat

I'm mtrying to run in eclipse my dinamic proyect ... is a webservice soap but it don't run aun trow this error

```
 GRAVE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase com.bankVision.webBanking.webServices.WebAppContextListener
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/bankVision/webBanking/util/NamingService
        at com.bankVision.webBanking.webServices.WebAppContextListener.contextInitialized(WebAppContextListener.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bankVision.webBanking.util.NamingService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 10 more
```

i have in the proyect import the other projects for use, and the class have the imports, too complie correctly

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bankVision.webBanking.util.NamingService` means that tomcat disagrees with you; keep in mind that importing the classes in Eclipse is not enough, they need to be exported in the WAR that will be built...

Comment: i did it ... too i try export the project like a .jar but it dont works